# How to use a Vector over ArrayList?

Tags: android, vector

I am using

```
String [] = {//Variables"}
```

To create an ArrayList.

I have been made aware the a Vector collection would be alot better.

If anyone know a tutorial, or wants to post an example of a Vector the give specific detail please help me out.

Thanks Alot.

Comment: By the way. You create array, not ArrayList. ArrayList is implementation of List interface and if you need List you can use Arrays.asList(arrayHere);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Vector is not usually a better choice because it is synchronized and has performance costs.

Also, your code does **not** create an ArrayList.  It is creating an array of Strings which is quite different.

What you really want to do is:

```
String [] myArray = {/*Variables*};
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vector's copyInto(String[]) to build a vector from string array.
Hope this helps.